# If statements not working when using multiple

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, loops

I have a form with a "state" select drop-down with 4 possible "carrier" select drop-downs (populated with php) based on the state chosen. My "display" button fires a url and appends the string "?id=" and the value of the ""carrier" select option (varies per state). The button works if I only use one if statement, but fails with multiple. Why is this? Also, I would like to use a loop instead of so many if statements. How can I achieve this? Thank you.

THE FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="company.php">
        <select name="state_select" id="state_select">
            <option selected disabled>Choose a state</option>
            <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
            <option value="2">New Hampshire</option>
            <option value="3">New Jersey</option>
            <option value="4">New York</option>
        </select>
</div>        
<div id="select-div1" class="select-div">
        <select name="conn_select" id="carrier_select1"  class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - Conn</option>
            <? $options = ''; foreach($company_arryCT as $company) {$options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";} echo $options; ?>     
        </select>
</div>
<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                      
        <select name="nh_select" id="carrier_select2" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NH</option>
            <? $options = ''; foreach($company_arryNH as $company) {$options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";} echo $options; ?>
        </select>
</div>
<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                       
        <select name="nj_select" id="carrier_select3" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NJ</option>
             <? $options = ''; foreach($company_arryNJ as $company) {$options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";}echo $options; ?>
        </select>
</div>
<div id ="select-div" class="select-div">                        
        <select name="ny_select" id="carrier_select4" class="carr-hide">
            <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NY</option>
            <? $options = ''; foreach($company_arry as $company) {$options .= "<option value='" . $company['Id'] . "'>" . $company['Name'] . "</option>";} echo $options; ?>
        </select>      
</div>
<div id="display" class="grid_2 greedy" style="display:none;">
        <button id="display-btn" class="button-link" onclick="appendUrl()">Display</button>
</div>
    </form>
```

THE JS FUNCTION:

```
function appendUrl(){
var stateOptions = document.getElementById('state_select');
var carrOptions1 = document.getElementById('carrier_select1');
var carrOptions2 = document.getElementById('carrier_select2');
var carrOptions3 = document.getElementById('carrier_select3');
var carrOptions4 = document.getElementById('carrier_select4');
var URL = "http://dev.pia.org/GIA/surveys/performance/archive/company.php";

if (stateOptions.value == 1){  
  window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions1.value, "_self");
}
if (stateOptions.value == 2){  
  window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions2.value, "_self");
}
if (stateOptions.value == 3){  
  window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions3.value, "_self");
}
if (stateOptions.value == 4){  
  window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions4.value, "_self");
}
}
```

DROP-DOWN JAVASCRIPT:

```
function optionCheck() {
    var i, len, optionVal, helpDiv,
        selectOptions = document.getElementById("state_select");

    // loop through the options in case there
    // are multiple selected values
    for (i = 0, len = selectOptions.options.length; i < len; i++) {

        // get the selected option value
        optionVal = selectOptions.options[i].value;

        // find the corresponding help div
        helpDiv = document.getElementById("carrier_select" + optionVal);
        displayButton = document.getElementById('display-btn');
        //selectDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("select-div");

        // move on if we didn't find one
        if (!helpDiv) { continue; }

        // set CSS classes to show/hide help div
        if (selectOptions.options[i].selected) {
            helpDiv.className = "conn_select nh_select nj_select ny_select";
            $(helpDiv).addClass("dropdown-box");
        } else {
            //Hide carrier select on page load
            helpDiv.className = "carr-hide";
            //Hide display button when changing states
            $('#display').hide();
        }
    }    
}

// alternative method of binding the onchange handler
document.getElementById("state_select").onchange = optionCheck;

//Remove emtpy 'options' generated by PHP
$('[class=carr-hide] option').filter(function(){
    return this.value == ''
}).remove();

//Show display button when acrrier is selected
document.getElementById('carrier_select1').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select2').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select3').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select4').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});
```

Comment: `(stateOptions.value = 1)` ??  Use `(stateOptions.value == 1)`

Comment: If you want to compare two values you must use == or ===. One '=' means assignment not comparison

Comment: Use Comparison operator to compare values, `if (stateOptions.value == 1)`

Comment: Try a [Switch Statement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: So I've changed that! Thanks guys, however it does not fix the issue. when i click display it does not append the string or value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things wrong with your code.

First, The way you are trying to retrieve the value of the selected option is wrong. The `HTMLElementObject.value` does not work for `<select>` elements. To retrieve the selected option, you have to use the `options` object of the given `<select>` element.

Secondly, instead of the comparison operator `==`, you are making use of the assignment operator `=`, a logic error which will make your test mostly evaluate true, giving you what you might not expect.

Having said that, below is a function that successfully retrieves the selected option value of a `<select>` element, and also a rewrite of your `appendUrl` function. With the use of the `switch` statement, giving a more succinct code, compared to multiple `if-else` statements, and of course a fix for your logical error. I hope it helps.

```
function getSelectElementSelectedValue(elemID)
{
    var selectElem = document.getElementById(elemID);

    if(typeof selectElem !== 'undefined')
    {         
       var optionsObj = selectElem['options'];
       var selectedValue = optionsObj[optionsObj['selectedIndex']].value;
       return selectedValue;
    }
    else 
    { 
      alert('Could not find element with give id : ' + elemID);//you might choose to use `console.log()` instead
    }
}


function appendUrl()
{
    var selectedState = getSelectElementSelectedValue('state_select');
    var selectedCarr1 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select1');
    var selectedCarr2 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select2');
    var selectedCarr3 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select3');
    var selectedCarr4 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select4');
    var URL = "http://dev.pia.org/GIA/surveys/performance/archive/company.php";

  switch(selectedState)
  {
    case 1 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr1, "_self"); break;

    case 2 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr2, "_self"); break;

    case 3 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr3, "_self"); break;

    case 4 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr4, "_self"); break;
  }
}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**
HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="company.php">
    <select name="state_select" id="state_select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a state</option>
        <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="2">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="3">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="4">New York</option>
    </select>
</div>        
<div id="select-div1" class="select-div">
    <select name="conn_select" id="carrier_select1"  class="carr-hide">
        <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - Conn</option>
        <option value="1">Conn 1</option>
        <option value="2">Conn 2</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                      
    <select name="nh_select" id="carrier_select2" class="carr-hide">
        <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NH</option>
        <option value="3">NH 3</option>
        <option value="4">NH 4</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="select-div" class="select-div">                       
    <select name="nj_select" id="carrier_select3" class="carr-hide">
        <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NJ</option>
         <option value="5">NJ 5</option>
        <option value="6">NJ 6</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id ="select-div" class="select-div">                        
    <select name="ny_select" id="carrier_select4" class="carr-hide">
        <option selected disabled>Select a carrier - NY</option>
        <option value="7">NY 7</option>
        <option value="8">NY 8</option>
    </select>      
</div>
<div id="display" class="grid_2 greedy" style="display:none;">
    <button id="display-btn" class="button-link">Display</button>
</div>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function optionCheck() { 
   var i, len, optionVal, helpDiv,
   selectOptions = document.getElementById("state_select");

   // loop through the options in case there
   // are multiple selected values
   for (i = 0, len = selectOptions.options.length; i < len; i++) {

       // get the selected option value
       optionVal = selectOptions.options[i].value;

       // find the corresponding help div
       helpDiv = document.getElementById("carrier_select" + optionVal);
       displayButton = document.getElementById('display-btn');
       //selectDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("select-div");

       // move on if we didn't find one
       if (!helpDiv) { continue; }

       // set CSS classes to show/hide help div
       if (selectOptions.options[i].selected) {
          helpDiv.className = "conn_select nh_select nj_select ny_select";
          $(helpDiv).addClass("dropdown-box");
       } else {
          //Hide carrier select on page load
          helpDiv.className = "carr-hide";
          //Hide display button when changing states
          $('#display').hide();
       }
   }    
}

// alternative method of binding the onchange handler
document.getElementById("state_select").onchange = optionCheck;

//Remove emtpy 'options' generated by PHP
$('[class=carr-hide] option').filter(function(){
    return this.value == ''
}).remove();

//Show display button when acrrier is selected
document.getElementById('carrier_select1').addEventListener('change', function () { 
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select2').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select3').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('carrier_select4').addEventListener('change', function () {
    var style = this.value > 0 ? 'block' : 'none';
    document.getElementById('display').style.display = style;
});

document.getElementById('display-btn').addEventListener('click', function () { 
    appendUrl();
});

function getSelectElementSelectedValue(elemID)
{
    var selectElem = document.getElementById(elemID);

   if(typeof selectElem !== 'undefined')
   {         
      var optionsObj = selectElem['options'];
      var selectedValue = optionsObj[optionsObj['selectedIndex']].value;
      return selectedValue;
   }
   else 
   { 
     alert('Could not find element with give id : ' + elemID);//you might choose to use `console.log()` instead
   }
}

function appendUrl()
{
    var selectedState = getSelectElementSelectedValue('state_select');
    var selectedCarr1 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select1');
    var selectedCarr2 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select2');
    var selectedCarr3 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select3');
    var selectedCarr4 = getSelectElementSelectedValue('carrier_select4');
    var URL = "http://dev.pia.org/GIA/surveys/performance/archive/company.php";

  switch(selectedState)
  {
    case 1 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr1, "_self"); break;

    case 2 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr2, "_self"); break;

    case 3 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr3, "_self"); break;

    case 4 : window.open(URL + '?id=' + selectedCarr4, "_self"); break;
  }
}
```

I created a working example, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/naijaprogrammer/tcjwwq2b/15/

Comment: is "getSelectElementSelectedValue" to be defined at the start as: "function getSelectElementSelectedValue('state_select' 'carrier_select1' etc...)?

Comment: Just use it as it appears in my answer.

Comment: Can I see how you are using it? Also, did you check your browser console to see the errors, if any, that it is issuing?

Comment: No errors. I am using your code exactly as is, below the "DROP-DOWN JAVASCRIPT:" section of my post. Your answer is the last piece of JS in the script section. All JS is in the same doc as the HTML, in the same order as in my post ( "THE JS FUNCTION:" is commented out of course).

Comment: I've updated my answer, and also created a working example of JSFiddle, you can just copy and paste the code, and adjust it to meet your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/naijaprogrammer/tcjwwq2b/15/

Comment: the fiddle cannot redirect to the "company.php" in the form, so I'm not sure how the fiddle is supposed to be a working example? Also, I have tried applying your updated code to no avail : ( Maybe I should be looking into achieving this in PHP?

Comment: I don't have your company.php file in my fiddle, you should know how to make the redirection to your page. In the fiddle, it's getting the values, and redirecting, that's the much I can do given the code in your question. I'd have to have more (possibly, your entire site structure) to do beyond that. At that stage, you'd no longer be a developer, you'd need to hire a developer.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you must put "==" instead of "=".

Moreover if it doesnt fixe your problem its because `state_select` is consider by JS like a "string" and not an "integer".

So try with quotes :

```
(...)
if (stateOptions.value == "1"){  
  window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions1.value, "_self");
} 
(...)
```

Comment: I've tried both of these suggestions, but no luck :(

Comment: Do you use Jquery also ? Because I just noticed your javascript is mixed "traditionnal javascript" and some Jquery. Its smells like that some code has been copy / paste from internet without knowing what it means ....

Comment: Yes. there is a bit of Jquery here and there. I've added the drop-down JS to the post hoping it helps. I basically states that if a state is selected, show the respective carrier select: If a carrier is selected, show the display button. Also there is JS that removes empty options populated by the php.

Comment: And do you include Jquery library in your page ? Moreover, do you have **firebug** plugin on your browser installed and activated ? If not, I suggest you to do it because its helpfull for javascript debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I modified your code to push it into the direction you wanted. This should(untested) work as long have the same number of inputs(i<5=4 selects)

```
function appendUrl(){
var stateOptions = document.getElementById('state_select');
var carrOptions;
for(i=1;i<5;i++)
{
   carrOptions[i-1] = document.getElementById('carrier_select'+i);
}
var URL ="http://dev.pia.org/GIA/surveys/performance/archive/company.php";
for(i=0;i<carrOptions.length;i++)
{
   if (stateOptions.value == (i+1)){  
     window.open(URL + '?id=' + carrOptions[i].value, "_self");
}

}
}
```

Comment: This looks great, but it breaks my drop-downs. I've added the JS for my drop-downs in the post. Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you explain in detail how it breaks your drop-downs? (because thats alot of code :D)

Comment: NP. So when a user selects a state the respective carrier drop-down is displayed. same for the display button after a carrier is selected. Adding your code, the carrier select does not display.

Comment: I edited my post because there was a little error in there can you try it out again and tell me if it worked? If it doesn´t the error is probably not part of the code i provided.

Comment: I get a syntax error when using this code. At the "for(i=1,i<5,i++)" line. I am putting it below the JS code for my drop-downs.

Comment: yeah i accidently addet "," indstead of ";" inside my for... so i guess that is the reason... but i fixed it now

Comment: No longer breaks the drop-downs, but still does not append the '?id=' and option value. It DOES take me to the url though.

Comment: @StevenSerrano It shoud at least add the `'?id'` at the end. i tested with `window.open(URL + '?id=' + id, "_self");` giving the same `URL`you use and an `id` of 1 and it worked for me. As far as i can see this should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an answer based on @NaijaProgrammer answer. What I've done was take out the "action" from my form and add it on the fly within my JS switch statement. Also adding ".value" to my switch variable and putting in quotes my case '1': case '2': etc. And on a final note, I changed the button tag to a simpler input-submit for my form. Thank you all for your help!

HTML CHANGES:

```
<form id ="stateCarrForm" method="post" name="stateCarrierForm">

    <select name="state_select" id="state_select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose a state</option>
        <option value="1">Connecticut</option>
        <option value="2">New Hampshire</option>
        <option value="3">New Jersey</option>
        <option value="4">New York</option>
    </select>
</form>

<div id="display" class="grid_2 greedy" style="display:none;">
    <input id="display-btn" class="button-link" type="submit" value="Display"/>
</div>
    </form>
```

JS CHANGES:

```
var selectedState = document.getElementById('state_select');
var carrOption1 = document.getElementById('carrier_select1');
var carrOption2 = document.getElementById('carrier_select2');
var carrOption3 = document.getElementById('carrier_select3');
var carrOption4 = document.getElementById('carrier_select4');

function appendUrl()
{
    switch (selectedState.value)
    {
    case '1': document.stateCarrierForm.action = "company.php?id=" + carrOption1.value; break;

    case '2': document.stateCarrierForm.action = "company.php?id=" + carrOption2.value; break;

    case '3': document.stateCarrierForm.action = "company.php?id=" + carrOption3.value; break;

    case '4': document.stateCarrierForm.action = "company.php?id=" + carrOption4.value; break;

    }
}
```